# Error when decoding json API ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16:

Tags: python, json, api

I am using `Python 3.8.5`
Just retriving json fron API.

```
url = "https://theapi.com/api"
uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url) 
data = uh.read().decode()
```

However for some data, there comes error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/whitebear/anaconda3/envs/myapp/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 555, in _get_chunk_left
    chunk_left = self._read_next_chunk_size()
  File "/Users/whitebear/anaconda3/envs/myapp/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 522, in _read_next_chunk_size
    return int(line, 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16:
```

I googled around and found that this is relevant with int() for some wrong data.

However I can't touch the third party API.

How can I fix it??

or there is alternative way to get json from API??

Comment: That means the server is not sending the correct HTTP protocol messages.

Comment: This doesn't look like a bug in your code, it looks like a problem with the API.